# Can one write 'Health behaviors'? I keep coming across this kind of usage in some research papers

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, vocabulary

"Analyzing health behaviors of diabetics" was the title of a paper. I was wondering about the usage.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe you can't write it?

Comment: Obviously, you have to look at the authors and institutions to see if they are trustworthy. As specialists, they will know better than anyone here.

Comment: The use of N + N pairs is very common, but novel pairings can be impossible to analyse. Does 'Nm + Nh' mean 'Nh is dictated/informed by Nm considerations' or just 'Nh relating in some way to Nh', etc? Idiomaticity (how often they are used in what is considered an acceptable way') determines acceptability. There's no structure-analytical method to determine acceptability.

Comment: There is nothing grammatically wrong with this construction, but, considered by itself, it only conveys that the 'behaviors' have something to do with health; it does not convey **what** they have to do with health. Chances are that the phrase has a more specific meaning within the jargon of the relevant field, but the questions about such specialised usage are likely to get a better answer if addressed to the specialists in that field.

Comment: Thanks. It just sounds awkward.